# Identifying total derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, pattern-matching, symbolic

I would like to identify which terms in my expression are a total derivative and which ones are not.

For expressions in which all terms are a total derivative, one can simply use integrate to find out. For instance, the following simple example nicely illustrates this:

`Integrate[f[x] f'[x] + g[x] h'[x] + g'[x] h[x], x]`

which yields

```
f[x]^2/2 + g[x] h[x]
```

However, for expressions that contain terms that are not total derivatives, this does not work.
For instance

```
Integrate[f[x] f'[x] + g[x] h'[x] + g'[x] h[x]+ g[x] k[x], x]
```

would not work. Mathematica just returns the same expression with an integral sign. I would like it to tell me that the first three terms are a total derivative and the last one is not.

Any other practical ways to go about this?

Comment: I do not understand what you would like to do. Could you provide an example of one expression where the `Integrate` approach does not work, together with the output you seek in that case?\

Comment: Sure, for instance Integrate[f[x] f'[x] + g[x] h'[x] + g'[x] h[x]+ g[x] k[x], x] would not work. Mathematica just returns the same expression with an integral sign. I would like it to tell me that the first three terms are a total derivative and the last one is not.

Comment: Got it. I have a proposed approach in an answer below. See if that is what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

Let's generate all possible partial sums of elements from your expression `expr` in the comments, then let us attempt to calculate the indefinite integral. Among these, we select only those that do *not* return an `Integrate` expression, i.e. those for which `Integrate` found an antiderivative:

```
expr = f[x] f'[x] + g[x] h'[x] + g'[x] h[x] + g[x] k[x];
res = Select[Subsets[expr] /. 0 -> Nothing, Head[Integrate[#, x]] =!= Integrate &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `/. 0 -> Nothing` part removes the spurious results caused by a subset containing no elements of the original expression (i.e. `Plus[]`).

If you want the largest subexpression among those, you can take the one with the largest `Length`:

```
MaximalBy[Length][res]
```

[image: only max]

Answer (score 3):

More examples might be needed to develop robustness, but this works:

```
Integrate[f[x] f'[x] + g[x] h'[x] + g'[x] h[x] + g[x] k[x], x] //. 
 Integrate[Plus[b__, c__], x_] :> 
  With[{i1 = Integrate[+b, x]}, i1 + Integrate[+c, x] /; FreeQ[i1, Integrate]]
(*  f[x]^2/2 + g[x]*h[x] + Integrate[g[x]*k[x], x]  *)
```